# How to drive a class (used to simulate an enum) iterable?

Tags: javascript, iterable

I use Javascript classes to simulate enums (don't suggest me to use Typescript please). When I enter `console.log(...MyEnumClass)`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: MyEnumClass is not iterable`.

I implement a generator but it doesn't work as expected:

```
class MyEnumClass {

    static A = new MyEnumClass("A");

    static B = new MyEnumClass("A");

    static #values = Object.freeze([MyEnumClass.A, MyEnumClass.B]);

    static values() {
        return MyEnumClass.#values;
    }

    static *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* MyEnumClass.#values;
    }

    #name;

    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }

    name() {
        return this.#name;
    }
}
```

Removing the static keyword before the generator declaration doesn't help. For now, I iterate over the array returned by `values()` but I'd like to find a better solution.

Comment: `Object.freeze([A, B])` is `Object.freeze([this.A, this.B])` no ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I need to refer to the class. See my edit.

Comment: What do you expect from `console.log`?

Comment: I expect Array(2) [ {}, {}] like when calling console.log(MyEnumClass.values()). It's a first test before using it in real scenarios. I would like to use the class in for ( of ).